# Lengthening the time it takes to access files using function hooking

Tags: c++, file-system, c++20, dynamic-loading

[https://github.com/speedrun-program/load_extender](https://github.com/speedrun-program/load_extender/tree/2e890b4bcb4f4191eb1ce7c2564d1841ddcf706f)

This is something I made and posted here about a year ago, but I decided to remake it.

To compile this on Windows, you need to install EasyHook.

load_extender_injector.cpp (only used on Windows because LD_PRELOAD and DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES can be used on Linux and Mac OS)

```cpp
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdio>
// easyhook.h installed with NuGet
// https://easyhook.github.io/documentation.html
#include <easyhook.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void getExitInput(char ch)
{
    for (; ch != '\n'; ch = std::getchar());

    printf("Press Enter to exit\n");
    ch = std::getchar();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WCHAR* dllToInject32 = nullptr;
    WCHAR* dllToInject64 = nullptr;
    _TCHAR* lpApplicationName = argv[0];
    DWORD lpBinaryType = 0;

    if (GetBinaryType(lpApplicationName, &lpBinaryType) == 0 || (lpBinaryType != 0 && lpBinaryType != 6))
    {
        std::printf("ERROR: This exe wasn't identified as 32-bit or as 64-bit\n");
        getExitInput('\n');
        return 0;
    }
    else if (lpBinaryType == 0)
    {
        dllToInject32 = (WCHAR*)L"load_extender_32.dll";
    }
    else
    {
        dllToInject64 = (WCHAR*)L"load_extender_64.dll";
    }

    std::printf("Enter the process Id: ");
    long long int PIDLongLong = 0;
    char ch = std::getchar();

    for (; ch != '\n'; ch = std::getchar())
    {
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        {
            ch = ch - '0'; // this prevents a warning message
            PIDLongLong *= 10;
            PIDLongLong += ch;
        }

        if (PIDLongLong > 4294967295)
        {
            std::printf("PID too large\n");
            getExitInput(ch);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    NTSTATUS nt = RhInjectLibrary(
        (DWORD)PIDLongLong,      // The process to inject into
        0,                       // ThreadId to wake up upon injection
        EASYHOOK_INJECT_DEFAULT,
        dllToInject32,           // 32-bit
        dllToInject64,           // 64-bit
        nullptr,                 // data to send to injected DLL entry point
        0                        // size of data to send
    );

    if (nt != 0)
    {
        std::printf("RhInjectLibrary failed with error code = %d\n", nt);
        PWCHAR err = RtlGetLastErrorString();
        std::printf("%ls\n", err);
        getExitInput(ch);
        return 0;
    }

    std::printf("Library injected successfully.\n");
    getExitInput(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

load_extender.cpp

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <climits>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>

#ifdef _WIN32
// easyhook.h installed with NuGet
// https://easyhook.github.io/documentation.html
#include <easyhook.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using wcharOrChar = wchar_t; // file paths are UTF-16LE on Windows
using strType = std::wstring;
using svType = std::wstring_view;
#else
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <dlfcn.h>
using wcharOrChar = char;
using strType = std::string;
using svType = std::string_view;
#endif

// using multiple cpp files made exe bigger, so definitions are in this header
#include "shared_stuff.h"

static myMapType m;
static std::mutex mutexForMap = setupMap(m);

#ifdef _WIN32
static NTSTATUS WINAPI NtCreateFileHook(
    PHANDLE            FileHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK        DesiredAccess,
    POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK   IoStatusBlock,
    PLARGE_INTEGER     AllocationSize,
    ULONG              FileAttributes,
    ULONG              ShareAccess,
    ULONG              CreateDisposition,
    ULONG              CreateOptions,
    PVOID              EaBuffer,
    ULONG              EaLength)
{
    const wchar_t* path = (const wchar_t*)(ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Buffer);
    int pathEndIndex = (ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Length) / sizeof(wchar_t);
    int filenameIndex = pathEndIndex;

    for (; filenameIndex >= 0 && path[filenameIndex] != '\\'; filenameIndex--);

    filenameIndex++; // moving past '\\' character or to 0 if no '\\' was found
    auto it = m.find(svType(path + filenameIndex, (size_t)pathEndIndex - filenameIndex));

    if (it != m.end())
    {
        delayFile(m, it->second, mutexForMap);
    }

    return NtCreateFile(
        FileHandle,
        DesiredAccess,
        ObjectAttributes,
        IoStatusBlock,
        AllocationSize,
        FileAttributes,
        ShareAccess,
        CreateDisposition,
        CreateOptions,
        EaBuffer,
        EaLength
    );
}

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall NativeInjectionEntryPoint(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO * inRemoteInfo);

void __stdcall NativeInjectionEntryPoint(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO* inRemoteInfo)
{
    HOOK_TRACE_INFO hHook1 = { nullptr };
    HMODULE moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll"));

    if (moduleHandle)
    {
        LhInstallHook(
            GetProcAddress(moduleHandle, "NtCreateFile"),
            NtCreateFileHook,
            nullptr,
            &hHook1
        );
    }

    ULONG ACLEntries[1] = { 0 };
    LhSetExclusiveACL(ACLEntries, 1, &hHook1);
}
#else
static auto originalFopen = reinterpret_cast<FILE * (*)(const char* path, const char* mode)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen"));

FILE* fopen(const char* path, const char* mode)
{
    int filenameIndex = -1;
    int pathEndIndex = 0;

    for (; path[pathEndIndex] != '\0'; pathEndIndex++)
    {
        if (path[pathEndIndex] == '/')
        {
            filenameIndex = pathEndIndex;
        }
    }
    
    filenameIndex++; // moving past '/' character or to 0 if no '/' was found
    auto it = m.find(svType(path + filenameIndex, (size_t)pathEndIndex - filenameIndex));
    
    if (it != m.end())
    {
        delayFile(m, it->second, mutexForMap);
    }

    return original_fopen(path, mode);
}
#endif
```

shared_stuff.h

```cpp
#ifndef DEBUG
#define printf(...) (0)
#endif

class FileHelper
{
public:
    FileHelper(const FileHelper& fh) = delete;
    FileHelper& operator=(FileHelper other) = delete;
    FileHelper(FileHelper&&) = delete;
    FileHelper& operator=(FileHelper&&) = delete;

    FileHelper() {}

    ~FileHelper()
    {
        if (_f)
        {
            std::fclose(_f);
        }

        if (_fcheck)
        {
            std::fclose(_fcheck);
        }
    }

    void tryToOpenFile(const char* filename)
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        if (fopen_s(&_f, filename, "rb") != 0 || !_f)
#else
        if (!(_f = std::fopen(filePath, "rb")))
#endif
        {
            throw "FileHelper fopen failure in tryToOpenFile";
        }
    }

    bool checkIfFileExists(const char* filename)
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        bool exists = fopen_s(&_fcheck, filename, "rb") == 0;
#else
        bool exists = (_fcheck = std::fopen(filePath, "rb"));
#endif

        if (_fcheck)
        {
            std::fclose(_fcheck);
            _fcheck = nullptr;
        }

        return exists;
    }

    bool getCharacter(wcharOrChar& ch)
    {
        if (_bufferPosition == _charactersRead)
        {
            _bufferPosition = 0;
            _charactersRead = (int)std::fread(_buffer.data(), sizeof(wcharOrChar), _buffer.size(), _f);

            if (!_charactersRead)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        ch = _buffer.at(_bufferPosition);
        _bufferPosition++;

        return true;
    }

    void resetFile() // used in tests
    {
        if (std::fseek(_f, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        {
            throw "FileHelper fseek failure in resetFile";
        }

        _bufferPosition = 0;
        _charactersRead = 0;
    }

private:
    FILE* _f = nullptr;
    FILE* _fcheck = nullptr;
    std::vector<wcharOrChar> _buffer = std::vector<wcharOrChar>(8192 / sizeof(wcharOrChar));
    int _bufferPosition = 0;
    int _charactersRead = 0;
};

struct MapValue
{
    std::vector<int> delays;
    size_t position = 0;
    unsigned int fullResetCheckNumber = 0;
    bool reset = false;
    bool resetAll = false;
};

struct KeyCmp
{
    using is_transparent = void;

    bool operator()(const svType sv1, const svType sv2) const
    {
        return sv1 == sv2;
    }
};

struct KeyHash
{
    using is_transparent = void;

    size_t operator()(const svType sv) const
    {
        return _hashObject(sv);
    }

private:
    std::hash<svType> _hashObject = std::hash<svType>();
};

using myMapType = std::unordered_map<strType, MapValue, KeyHash, KeyCmp>;

static bool makeMapValue(std::vector<int>& delaysVector, MapValue& mv, FileHelper& fh)
{
    wcharOrChar ch = '\0';
    bool textRemaining = false;
    long long int delay = 0;

    for (
        textRemaining = fh.getCharacter(ch);
        ch != '\n' && textRemaining;
        textRemaining = fh.getCharacter(ch))
    {
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        {
            ch = ch - '0'; // this prevents a warning message
            delay *= 10;
            delay += ch;

            if (delay > INT_MAX)
            {
                throw "delays can't be larger than INT_MAX";
            }
        }
        else if (ch == '-')
        {
            if (delaysVector.empty())
            {
                mv.resetAll = true;
            }
            else
            {
                mv.reset = true;
            }

            break;
        }
        else if (ch == '/')
        {
            delaysVector.push_back((int)delay);
            delay = 0;
        }
    }

    if (delay != 0 && !mv.reset && !mv.resetAll)
    {
        delaysVector.push_back((int)delay);
    }

    // make sure to go to end of line
    for (; ch != '\n' && textRemaining; textRemaining = fh.getCharacter(ch));

    return textRemaining;
}

static bool addMapPair(myMapType& m, strType& keyStr, std::vector<int>& delaysVector, FileHelper& fh)
{
    keyStr.clear();
    delaysVector.clear();
    MapValue mv;
    wcharOrChar ch = '\0';
    bool keepWhitespace = false;
    bool textRemaining = fh.getCharacter(ch);

    if (ch == '\n' || !textRemaining)
    {
        return textRemaining;
    }
    else if (ch == '/')
    {
        keepWhitespace = true;
    }
    else if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\f' && ch != '\r' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\v')
    {
        keyStr.push_back(ch);
    }

    for (
        textRemaining = fh.getCharacter(ch);
        ch != '\n' && ch != '/' && textRemaining;
        textRemaining = fh.getCharacter(ch))
    {
        if (keepWhitespace || (ch != ' ' && ch != '\f' && ch != '\r' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\v'))
        {
            keyStr.push_back(ch);
        }
    }

    if (textRemaining && ch == '/')
    {
        textRemaining = makeMapValue(delaysVector, mv, fh);
    }

    if (!keyStr.empty() && (!delaysVector.empty() || mv.resetAll))
    {
        mv.delays = delaysVector;
        strType keyStrCopy(keyStr);
        mv.delays.shrink_to_fit();
        keyStrCopy.shrink_to_fit();
        m.emplace(std::move(keyStrCopy), std::move(mv));
    }

    return textRemaining;
}

static std::mutex setupMap(myMapType& m)
{
    try
    {
        std::wstring keyStr;
        std::vector<int> delaysVector;
        FileHelper fh;

        if (!fh.checkIfFileExists("files_and_delays0.txt"))
        {
            fh.tryToOpenFile("files_and_delays.txt");
            printf("opened files_and_delays.txt\n");
        }
        else
        {
            std::string name("files_and_delays1.txt");
            unsigned int n = 1;

            while (fh.checkIfFileExists(name.c_str()))
            {
                n++;
                name = std::string("files_and_delays" + std::to_string(n) + ".txt");
            }

            name = std::string("files_and_delays" + std::to_string(n - 1) + ".txt");
            fh.tryToOpenFile(name.c_str());
            printf("opened %s\n", name.c_str());
        }

#ifdef _WIN32
        wchar_t byteOrderMark = '\0';

        if (!fh.getCharacter(byteOrderMark))
        {
            printf(
                "files_and_delays.txt byte order mark is missing\n\
                make sure files_and_delays.txt is saved as UTF-16 LE\n"
            );
        }
        else if (byteOrderMark != 0xFEFF) // not 0xFFFE because of how wchar_t is read
        {
            printf(
                "files_and_delays.txt byte order mark isn't marked as UTF-16 LE\n\
                make sure files_and_delays.txt is saved as UTF-16 LE\n"
            );
        }
#endif

        while (addMapPair(m, keyStr, delaysVector, fh));
    }
    catch (char const* e)
    {
        char const* resolveC4101Warning = e;
        printf("%s\n", resolveC4101Warning);
        m.clear(); // clear map so failure is more obvious
    }

    return std::mutex();
}

static void delayFile(myMapType& m, MapValue& mv, std::mutex& mutexForMap)
{
#ifndef DEBUG // this needs to be reset in the test, so it's a global variable instead
    static unsigned int fullResetCount = 0;
#endif

    printf("fullResetCount: %zu\n", fullResetCount);
    int delay = 0;

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mutexForMapLock(mutexForMap);

        if (mv.fullResetCheckNumber < fullResetCount)
        {
            mv.position = 0;
            mv.fullResetCheckNumber = fullResetCount;
            printf("this delay sequence reset due to prior full reset\n");
        }

        if (mv.resetAll)
        {
            if (fullResetCount == UINT_MAX) // this probably won't ever happen
            {
                fullResetCount = 0;

                for (auto& it : m)
                {
                    it.second.fullResetCheckNumber = 0;
                }

                printf("fullResetCount reset\n");
            }

            fullResetCount++;
            printf("fullResetCount set to %zu, all sequences will be reset\n", fullResetCount);
        }
        else if (mv.position == mv.delays.size())
        {
            if (mv.reset)
            {
                mv.position = 0;
                printf("this delay sequence reset\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("delay sequence already finished\n");
            }
        }

        if (mv.position < mv.delays.size())
        {
            delay = mv.delays.at(mv.position);
            mv.position++;
        }

        printf("delay is %d millisecond(s)\n\n", delay);
    }

    if (delay > 0)
    {
#ifndef DEBUG
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
#endif
    }
}
```

load_extender_test.cpp

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <climits>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#ifdef _WIN32
using wcharOrChar = wchar_t; // file paths are UTF-16LE on Windows
using strType = std::wstring;
using svType = std::wstring_view;
#else
using wcharOrChar = char;
using strType = std::string;
using svType = std::string_view;
#endif

#define DEBUG
unsigned int fullResetCount = 0;

// using multiple cpp files made exe bigger, so definitions are in this header
#include "shared_stuff.h"

void windowsHookFunction(myMapType& m, strType& pathStr, std::mutex& mutexForMap)
{
    if (!pathStr.empty() && pathStr.back() == '\r')
    {
        pathStr.pop_back();
    }

    const wcharOrChar* path = pathStr.c_str();

    int pathEndIndex = (int)pathStr.size();
    int filenameIndex = pathEndIndex;

    for (; filenameIndex >= 0 && path[filenameIndex] != '\\'; filenameIndex--);

    filenameIndex++; // moving past '\\' character or to 0 if no '\\' was found
    auto it = m.find(svType(path + filenameIndex, (size_t)pathEndIndex - filenameIndex));

    if (it != m.end())
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        printf("\n%ls found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#else
        printf("\n%s found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#endif
        delayFile(m, it->second, mutexForMap);
    }
    else
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        printf("\n%ls not found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#else
        printf("\n%s not found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#endif
    }
}

void unixHookFunction(myMapType& m, strType& pathStr, std::mutex& mutexForMap)
{
    if (!pathStr.empty() && pathStr.back() == '\r')
    {
        pathStr.pop_back();
    }

    const wcharOrChar* path = pathStr.c_str();

    int filenameIndex = -1;
    int pathEndIndex = 0;

    for (; path[pathEndIndex] != '\0'; pathEndIndex++)
    {
        if (path[pathEndIndex] == '/')
        {
            filenameIndex = pathEndIndex;
        }
    }

    filenameIndex++; // moving past '/' character or to 0 if no '/' was found
    auto it = m.find(svType(path + filenameIndex, (size_t)pathEndIndex - filenameIndex));

    if (it != m.end())
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        printf("\n%ls found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#else
        printf("\n%s found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#endif
        delayFile(m, it->second, mutexForMap);
    }
    else
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        printf("\n%ls not found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#else
        printf("\n%s not found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#endif
    }
}

void printMap(const myMapType& m)
{
    for (auto& it : m)
    {
        printf(
#ifdef _WIN32
            "%ls : fullResetCheckNumber %zu : position %zu : ",
#else
            "%s : fullResetCheckNumber %zu : position %zu : ",
#endif
            it.first.c_str(),
            it.second.fullResetCheckNumber,
            it.second.position
        );

        for (size_t i = 0; i < it.second.delays.size(); i++)
        {
            printf("%d / ", it.second.delays.at(i));
        }

        if (it.second.reset)
        {
            printf("RESET");
        }
        else if (it.second.resetAll)
        {
            printf("RESET ALL");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void testFunctions(myMapType& m, FileHelper& fh, std::mutex& mutexForMap, bool testUnix)
{
    strType pathStr;
    wcharOrChar ch = '\0';

    while (fh.getCharacter(ch))
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            if (testUnix)
            {
                unixHookFunction(m, pathStr, mutexForMap);
            }
            else
            {
                windowsHookFunction(m, pathStr, mutexForMap);
            }

            printMap(m);
            pathStr.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            pathStr.push_back(ch);
        }
    }

    if (testUnix)
    {
        unixHookFunction(m, pathStr, mutexForMap);
    }
    else
    {
        windowsHookFunction(m, pathStr, mutexForMap);
    }
}

void testInputs(myMapType& m, std::mutex& mutexForMap)
{
    FileHelper fh;
    fh.tryToOpenFile("test_input.txt");
    wcharOrChar byteOrderMark = '\0';
#ifdef _WIN32

    if (!fh.getCharacter(byteOrderMark))
    {
        printf(
            "test_input.txt byte order mark is missing\n\
            save test_input.txt as UTF-16 LE\n\n"
        );

        return;
    }
    else if (byteOrderMark != 0xFEFF) // not 0xFFFE because of how wchar_t is read
    {
        printf(
            "test_input.txt byte order mark isn't marked as UTF-16 LE\n\
            make sure files_and_delays.txt is saved as UTF-16 LE\n\n"
        );
    }
#endif
    printf("\ntesting UNIX\n\n - - - - - - - - - -\n\n");
    printMap(m);
    testFunctions(m, fh, mutexForMap, true);
    printMap(m);
    fullResetCount = 0;
    fh.resetFile();
#ifdef _WIN32
    fh.getCharacter(byteOrderMark);
#endif

    for (auto& it : m)
    {
        it.second.position = 0;
        it.second.fullResetCheckNumber = 0;
    }

    printf("\n\ntesting Windows\n\n - - - - - - - - - -\n\n");
    printMap(m);
    testFunctions(m, fh, mutexForMap, false);
    printMap(m);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        printf("\ntest start\n\n");
        myMapType m;
        std::mutex mutexForMap = setupMap(m);
        testInputs(m, mutexForMap);
    }
    catch (char const* e)
    {
        printf("%s", e);
    }

    printf("\ntest finished, press Enter to exit\n");
    char ch = getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Updated version: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276167/update-1-lengthening-the-time-it-takes-to-access-files-using-function-hooking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use more C++

You tagged your question with C++20, but you are not making full use of it. In fact, you even rely a lot on C functions when there are much better C++ equivalents.

Prefer `<iostream>` over `<cstdio>`. Since C++17, you have [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) so you can format strings in a way similar to C's `printf()`, albeit with a slightly different syntax. For example, you can write:

```
auto name = std::format("files_and_delays{}.txt", n);
...
std::cout << std::format("opened {}\n", name);
```

Note that this is type safe and understands many C++ types, like `std::string`s. In the future you might even be able to use [`std::print()`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2093r14.html).

You can also use C++17's [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). For example, if you want to get the filename component from a path:

```
std::filesystem::path path{(const wchar_t*)(ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Buffer)};

if (auto it = m.find(path.filename()); it != m.end()) {
    delayFile(m, it->second, mutexForMap);
}
```

There are even things that are provided by C++ from the previous millenium, like reading an integer from the standard input:

```
std::cout << "Enter the process ID: ";
long long int PID;
std::cin >> PID;
```

## Naming things

Some of the names of variables, types or even files are badly chosen. Make sure things have concise and descriptive names, but are not abbreviated too much. Give a bit more thought to what a good name is; it will be nice for others that have to work with your code, but also for yourself in the future. Some examples of names that can be improved:

- `"shared_stuff.h"`: words like "stuff" and "thing" have almost no meaning. I see this file contains `FileHelper` and a lot of map related functions. Perhaps it can be split into two files: `"filehelper.h"` and `"map.h"`. If you really do just want a bucket of shared stuff, I would just name it `"shared.h"`.
- `PIDLongLong`: I would avoid adding the type of a variable into the name of a variable if possible.
- `lpBinaryType`: I know the Windows API uses [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), but even [Microsoft discourages it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/windows-coding-conventions#hungarian-notation). I would avoid using it, but if you really do want to use it, at least follow its [rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/coding-style-conventions). The `lp` prefix is for long pointers, not for `DWORD`s which should use the `dw` prefix.
- `m`: avoid single-letter names, unless it's something that is in very common use, like `i` for loop indices, or `x` and `y` for coordinates. I would choose `map` or `fileMap` instead as the name for this variable.

## Create a `class` for managing the file map

You have a separate `std::unordered_map` and a `std::mutex`. However, these are tightly coupled. There are also some helper functions that set up the map and add items to it. I would create a new `class` for that and group everything in there. You can turn `setupMap()` into the constructor for this class.

## Add a constructor to `struct MapValue`

Turn `makeMapValue()` into the constructor of `MapValue`.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I tried adding all your suggestions except for std::format, because for some reason it increased the exe size from 12 KB to 178 KB, so instead I put a note saying to replace std::printf and std::cout with std::print once it's available. I put the new code on the github page. Does it seem okay now?

Comment: Great! Just create a new question here on CodeReview with the new version, so we can review it again. The code size increase is unfortunate, and I'm afraid `std::print()` will have the same issue. So if you want a small executable, I guess it's better to stay with `printf()` then.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I posted it again: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276167/update-1-lengthening-the-time-it-takes-to-access-files-using-function-hooking