# UPDATE #1: Lengthening the time it takes to access files using function hooking

Tags: c++, file-system, c++20, dynamic-loading

[https://github.com/speedrun-program/load_extender](https://github.com/speedrun-program/load_extender/tree/21dc712d43ccfa3e382dc831543e199f269cbb0e)

This is the previous post: [Lengthening the time it takes to access files using function hooking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276098/lengthening-the-time-it-takes-to-access-files-using-function-hooking)

I tried adding everything from the previous post's answer, but I decided to stay with printf for output because it was pointed out that std::format makes the exe size large. I also decided to avoid std::filesystem::exists because it causes an 8-10 KB exe size increase.

To compile this on Windows, you need to install EasyHook.

load_extender_injector.cpp (only used on Windows because LD_PRELOAD and DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES can be used on Linux and Mac OS)

```cpp
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <climits>
// easyhook.h installed with NuGet
// https://easyhook.github.io/documentation.html
#include <easyhook.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void getExitInput()
{
    int ch = 0;

    for (; ch != '\n'; ch = std::getchar());

    std::printf("Press Enter to exit\n");
    ch = std::getchar();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WCHAR* dllToInject32 = nullptr;
    WCHAR* dllToInject64 = nullptr;
    _TCHAR* applicationName = argv[0];
    DWORD binaryType = 0;
    BOOL getBinaryTypeResult = GetBinaryType(applicationName, &binaryType);

    if (getBinaryTypeResult == 0 || (binaryType != 0 && binaryType != 6))
    {
        std::printf("ERROR: This exe wasn't identified as 32-bit or as 64-bit\n");
        getExitInput();
        return 0;
    }
    else if (binaryType == 0)
    {
        dllToInject32 = (WCHAR*)L"load_extender_32.dll";
    }
    else
    {
        dllToInject64 = (WCHAR*)L"load_extender_64.dll";
    }

    std::printf("Enter the process Id: ");
    DWORD pid = 0;
    std::cin >> pid;

    NTSTATUS errorCode = RhInjectLibrary(
        pid,                     // The process to inject into
        0,                       // ThreadId to wake up upon injection
        EASYHOOK_INJECT_DEFAULT,
        dllToInject32,           // 32-bit
        dllToInject64,           // 64-bit
        nullptr,                 // data to send to injected DLL entry point
        0                        // size of data to send
    );

    if (errorCode != 0)
    {
        std::printf("RhInjectLibrary failed with error code = %d\n", errorCode);
        PWCHAR errorMessage = RtlGetLastErrorString();
        std::printf("%ls\n", errorMessage);
        getExitInput();
        return 0;
    }

    std::printf("Library injected successfully.\n");
    getExitInput();
    return 0;
}
```

load_extender.cpp

```cpp
#include <climits>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>

#ifdef _WIN32
// easyhook.h installed with NuGet
// https://easyhook.github.io/documentation.html
#include <easyhook.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using wcharOrChar = wchar_t; // file paths are UTF-16LE on Windows
using strType = std::wstring;
using svType = std::wstring_view;
#else
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <dlfcn.h>
using wcharOrChar = char;
using strType = std::string;
using svType = std::string_view;
#endif

// using multiple cpp files made exe bigger, so definitions are in this header
#include "shared.h"

static MapAndMutex mapAndMutexObject;

#ifdef _WIN32
static NTSTATUS WINAPI NtCreateFileHook(
    PHANDLE            FileHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK        DesiredAccess,
    POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK   IoStatusBlock,
    PLARGE_INTEGER     AllocationSize,
    ULONG              FileAttributes,
    ULONG              ShareAccess,
    ULONG              CreateDisposition,
    ULONG              CreateOptions,
    PVOID              EaBuffer,
    ULONG              EaLength)
{
    const wchar_t* path = (const wchar_t*)(ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Buffer);
    int pathEndIndex = (ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Length) / sizeof(wchar_t);
    int filenameIndex = pathEndIndex;

    for (; filenameIndex >= 0 && path[filenameIndex] != '\\'; filenameIndex--);

    filenameIndex++; // moving past '\\' character or to 0 if no '\\' was found
    auto it = mapAndMutexObject.fileMap.find(
        svType(path + filenameIndex,
        (size_t)pathEndIndex - filenameIndex)
    );

    if (it != mapAndMutexObject.fileMap.end())
    {
        mapAndMutexObject.delayFile(it->second);
    }

    return NtCreateFile(
        FileHandle,
        DesiredAccess,
        ObjectAttributes,
        IoStatusBlock,
        AllocationSize,
        FileAttributes,
        ShareAccess,
        CreateDisposition,
        CreateOptions,
        EaBuffer,
        EaLength
    );
}

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall NativeInjectionEntryPoint(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO * inRemoteInfo);

void __stdcall NativeInjectionEntryPoint(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO* inRemoteInfo)
{
    HOOK_TRACE_INFO hHook1 = { nullptr };
    HMODULE moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll"));

    if (moduleHandle)
    {
        LhInstallHook(
            GetProcAddress(moduleHandle, "NtCreateFile"),
            NtCreateFileHook,
            nullptr,
            &hHook1
        );
    }

    ULONG ACLEntries[1] = { 0 };
    LhSetExclusiveACL(ACLEntries, 1, &hHook1);
}
#else
static auto originalFopen = reinterpret_cast<FILE * (*)(const char* path, const char* mode)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen"));

FILE* fopen(const char* path, const char* mode)
{
    int filenameIndex = -1;
    int pathEndIndex = 0;

    for (; path[pathEndIndex] != '\0'; pathEndIndex++)
    {
        if (path[pathEndIndex] == '/')
        {
            filenameIndex = pathEndIndex;
        }
    }
    
    filenameIndex++; // moving past '/' character or to 0 if no '/' was found
    auto it = mapAndMutexObject.fileMap.find(
        svType(path + filenameIndex,
        (size_t)pathEndIndex - filenameIndex)
    );
    
    if (it != mapAndMutexObject.fileMap.end())
    {
        delayFile(it->second);
    }

    return original_fopen(path, mode);
}
#endif
```

shared.h

```cpp
#ifndef DEBUG
#define printf(...) (0)
#endif

class FileHelper
{
public:
    FileHelper(const FileHelper& fhelper) = delete;
    FileHelper& operator=(FileHelper other) = delete;
    FileHelper(FileHelper&&) = delete;
    FileHelper& operator=(FileHelper&&) = delete;

    FileHelper() {}

    ~FileHelper()
    {
        if (_f)
        {
            std::fclose(_f);
        }
    }

    void tryToOpenFile(const char* filename)
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        if (fopen_s(&_f, filename, "rb") != 0 || !_f)
#else
        if (!(_f = std::fopen(filePath, "rb")))
#endif
        {
            throw "FileHelper fopen failure in tryToOpenFile";
        }
    }

    bool checkIfFileExists(std::string&& filename)
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        bool exists = fopen_s(&_fcheck, filename.c_str(), "rb") == 0;
#else
        bool exists = (_fcheck = std::fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb"));
#endif

        if (_fcheck)
        {
            std::fclose(_fcheck);
            _fcheck = nullptr;
        }

        return exists;
    }

    bool getCharacter(wcharOrChar& ch)
    {
        if (_bufferPosition == _charactersRead)
        {
            _bufferPosition = 0;
            _charactersRead = (int)std::fread(_buffer.data(), sizeof(wcharOrChar), _buffer.size(), _f);

            if (!_charactersRead)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        ch = _buffer.at(_bufferPosition);
        _bufferPosition++;

        return true;
    }

    void resetFile() // used in tests
    {
        if (std::fseek(_f, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        {
            throw "FileHelper fseek failure in resetFile";
        }

        _bufferPosition = 0;
        _charactersRead = 0;
    }

private:
    FILE* _f = nullptr;
    FILE* _fcheck = nullptr;
    std::vector<wcharOrChar> _buffer = std::vector<wcharOrChar>(8192 / sizeof(wcharOrChar));
    int _bufferPosition = 0;
    int _charactersRead = 0;
};

struct MapValue
{
    std::vector<int> delays;
    size_t position = 0;
    unsigned int fullResetCheckNumber = 0;
    bool reset = false;
    bool resetAll = false;

    MapValue(bool& textRemaining, std::vector<int>& delaysVector, FileHelper& fhelper)
    {
        wcharOrChar ch = '\0';
        long long int delay = 0;

        for (
            textRemaining = fhelper.getCharacter(ch);
            ch != '\n' && textRemaining;
            textRemaining = fhelper.getCharacter(ch))
        {
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            {
                ch = ch - '0';
                delay *= 10;
                delay += ch;

                if (delay > INT_MAX)
                {
                    throw "delays can't be larger than INT_MAX";
                }
            }
            else if (ch == '-')
            {
                if (delaysVector.empty())
                {
                    resetAll = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    reset = true;
                }

                break;
            }
            else if (ch == '/')
            {
                delaysVector.push_back((int)delay);
                delay = 0;
            }
        }

        if (delay != 0 && !reset && !resetAll)
        {
            delaysVector.push_back((int)delay);
        }

        // make sure to go to end of line
        for (; ch != '\n' && textRemaining; textRemaining = fhelper.getCharacter(ch));
    }
};

struct KeyCmp
{
    using is_transparent = void;

    bool operator()(const svType sv1, const svType sv2) const
    {
        return sv1 == sv2;
    }
};

struct KeyHash
{
    using is_transparent = void;

    size_t operator()(const svType sv) const
    {
        return _hashObject(sv);
    }

private:
    std::hash<svType> _hashObject = std::hash<svType>();
};

using myMapType = std::unordered_map<strType, MapValue, KeyHash, KeyCmp>;

class MapAndMutex
{
public:
    std::mutex mutexForMap;
    myMapType fileMap;

    MapAndMutex()
    {
        try
        {
            std::wstring keyStr;
            std::vector<int> delaysVector;
            FileHelper fhelper;
            std::string filename("files_and_delays.txt");
            size_t fileNumber = 0;

            // std::filesystem::exists caused 10 KB exe size increase
            for (
                ;
                fhelper.checkIfFileExists("files_and_delays" + std::to_string(fileNumber) + ".txt");
                fileNumber++);

            if (fileNumber > 0)
            {
                filename = "files_and_delays" + std::to_string(fileNumber - 1) + ".txt";
            }

            fhelper.tryToOpenFile(filename.c_str());
#ifdef _WIN32
            wchar_t byteOrderMark = '\0';

            if (!fhelper.getCharacter(byteOrderMark))
            {
                printf(
                    "files_and_delays.txt byte order mark is missing\n\
                make sure files_and_delays.txt is saved as UTF-16 LE\n"
                );
            }
            else if (byteOrderMark != 0xFEFF) // not 0xFFFE due to how wchar_t is read
            {
                printf(
                    "files_and_delays.txt byte order mark isn't marked as UTF-16 LE\n\
                make sure files_and_delays.txt is saved as UTF-16 LE\n"
                );
            }
#endif

            while (addMapPair(fileMap, keyStr, delaysVector, fhelper));
        }
        catch (char const* e)
        {
            char const* resolveC4101Warning = e;
            printf("%s\n", resolveC4101Warning);
            fileMap.clear(); // clear map so failure is more obvious
        }
    }

    bool addMapPair(myMapType& fileMap, strType& keyStr, std::vector<int>& delaysVector, FileHelper& fhelper)
    {
        keyStr.clear();
        delaysVector.clear();
        wcharOrChar ch = '\0';
        bool keepWhitespace = false;
        bool textRemaining = fhelper.getCharacter(ch);

        if (ch == '\n' || !textRemaining)
        {
            return textRemaining;
        }
        else if (ch == '/')
        {
            keepWhitespace = true;
        }
        else if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\f' && ch != '\r' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\v')
        {
            keyStr.push_back(ch);
        }

        for (
            textRemaining = fhelper.getCharacter(ch);
            ch != '\n' && ch != '/' && textRemaining;
            textRemaining = fhelper.getCharacter(ch))
        {
            if (keepWhitespace || (ch != ' ' && ch != '\f' && ch != '\r' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\v'))
            {
                keyStr.push_back(ch);
            }
        }

        if (textRemaining && ch == '/')
        {
            MapValue fileMapValue(textRemaining, delaysVector, fhelper);

            if (!keyStr.empty() && (!delaysVector.empty() || fileMapValue.resetAll))
            {
                fileMapValue.delays = delaysVector;
                strType keyStrCopy(keyStr);
                fileMapValue.delays.shrink_to_fit();
                keyStrCopy.shrink_to_fit();
                fileMap.emplace(std::move(keyStrCopy), std::move(fileMapValue));
            }
        }

        return textRemaining;
    }

    void delayFile(MapValue& fileMapValue)
    {
#ifndef DEBUG // this needs to be reset in the test, so it's a global variable instead
        static unsigned int fullResetCount = 0;
#endif

        printf("fullResetCount: %zu\n", fullResetCount);
        int delay = 0;

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mutexForMapLock(mutexForMap);

            if (fileMapValue.fullResetCheckNumber < fullResetCount)
            {
                fileMapValue.position = 0;
                fileMapValue.fullResetCheckNumber = fullResetCount;
                printf("this delay sequence reset due to prior full reset\n");
            }

            if (fileMapValue.resetAll)
            {
                if (fullResetCount == UINT_MAX) // this probably won't ever happen
                {
                    fullResetCount = 0;

                    for (auto& it : fileMap)
                    {
                        it.second.fullResetCheckNumber = 0;
                    }

                    printf("fullResetCount reset\n");
                }

                fullResetCount++;
                printf("fullResetCount set to %zu, all sequences will be reset\n", fullResetCount);
            }
            else if (fileMapValue.position == fileMapValue.delays.size())
            {
                if (fileMapValue.reset)
                {
                    fileMapValue.position = 0;
                    printf("this delay sequence reset\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("delay sequence already finished\n");
                }
            }

            if (fileMapValue.position < fileMapValue.delays.size())
            {
                delay = fileMapValue.delays.at(fileMapValue.position);
                fileMapValue.position++;
            }

            printf("delay is %d millisecond(s)\n\n", delay);
        }

        if (delay > 0)
        {
#ifndef DEBUG
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
#endif
        }
    }
};
```

load_extender_test.cpp

```cpp
#include <climits>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#ifdef _WIN32
using wcharOrChar = wchar_t; // file paths are UTF-16LE on Windows
using strType = std::wstring;
using svType = std::wstring_view;
#else
using wcharOrChar = char;
using strType = std::string;
using svType = std::string_view;
#endif

#define DEBUG
unsigned int fullResetCount = 0;

// using multiple cpp files made exe bigger, so definitions are in this header
#include "shared.h"

void windowsHookFunction(MapAndMutex& mapAndMutexObject, strType& pathStr)
{
    if (!pathStr.empty() && pathStr.back() == '\r')
    {
        pathStr.pop_back();
    }

    const wcharOrChar* path = pathStr.c_str();

    // in the actual program, this will always be less than INT_MAX
    int pathEndIndex = pathStr.size() < INT_MAX ? (int)pathStr.size() : INT_MAX;
    int filenameIndex = pathEndIndex;

    for (; filenameIndex >= 0 && path[filenameIndex] != '\\'; filenameIndex--);

    filenameIndex++; // moving past '\\' character or to 0 if no '\\' was found
    auto it = mapAndMutexObject.fileMap.find(
        svType(path + filenameIndex,
        (size_t)pathEndIndex - filenameIndex)
    );

    if (it != mapAndMutexObject.fileMap.end())
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        printf("\n%ls found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#else
        printf("\n%s found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#endif
        mapAndMutexObject.delayFile(it->second);
    }
    else
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        printf("\n%ls not found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#else
        printf("\n%s not found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#endif
    }
}

void unixHookFunction(MapAndMutex& mapAndMutexObject, strType& pathStr)
{
    if (!pathStr.empty() && pathStr.back() == '\r')
    {
        pathStr.pop_back();
    }

    const wcharOrChar* path = pathStr.c_str();

    int filenameIndex = -1;
    int pathEndIndex = 0;

    for (; path[pathEndIndex] != '\0'; pathEndIndex++)
    {
        if (path[pathEndIndex] == '/')
        {
            filenameIndex = pathEndIndex;
        }
    }

    filenameIndex++; // moving past '/' character or to 0 if no '/' was found
    auto it = mapAndMutexObject.fileMap.find(
        svType(path + filenameIndex,
        (size_t)pathEndIndex - filenameIndex)
    );

    if (it != mapAndMutexObject.fileMap.end())
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        printf("\n%ls found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#else
        printf("\n%s found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#endif
        mapAndMutexObject.delayFile(it->second);
    }
    else
    {
#ifdef _WIN32
        printf("\n%ls not found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#else
        printf("\n%s not found in map\n", pathStr.c_str());
#endif
    }
}

void printMap(const myMapType& fileMap)
{
    for (auto& it : fileMap)
    {
        printf(
#ifdef _WIN32
            "%ls : fullResetCheckNumber %zu : position %zu : ",
#else
            "%s : fullResetCheckNumber %zu : position %zu : ",
#endif
            it.first.c_str(),
            it.second.fullResetCheckNumber,
            it.second.position
        );

        for (size_t i = 0; i < it.second.delays.size(); i++)
        {
            printf("%d / ", it.second.delays.at(i));
        }

        if (it.second.reset)
        {
            printf("RESET");
        }
        else if (it.second.resetAll)
        {
            printf("RESET ALL");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void testFunctions(MapAndMutex& mapAndMutexObject, FileHelper& fhelper, bool testUnix)
{
    strType pathStr;
    wcharOrChar ch = '\0';

    while (fhelper.getCharacter(ch))
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            if (testUnix)
            {
                unixHookFunction(mapAndMutexObject, pathStr);
            }
            else
            {
                windowsHookFunction(mapAndMutexObject, pathStr);
            }

            printMap(mapAndMutexObject.fileMap);
            pathStr.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            pathStr.push_back(ch);
        }
    }

    if (testUnix)
    {
        unixHookFunction(mapAndMutexObject, pathStr);
    }
    else
    {
        windowsHookFunction(mapAndMutexObject, pathStr);
    }
}

void testInputs(MapAndMutex& mapAndMutexObject)
{
    FileHelper fhelper;
    fhelper.tryToOpenFile("test_input.txt");
    wcharOrChar byteOrderMark = '\0';
#ifdef _WIN32

    if (!fhelper.getCharacter(byteOrderMark))
    {
        printf(
            "test_input.txt byte order mark is missing\n\
            save test_input.txt as UTF-16 LE\n\n"
        );

        return;
    }
    else if (byteOrderMark != 0xFEFF) // not 0xFFFE due to how wchar_t is read
    {
        printf(
            "test_input.txt byte order mark isn't marked as UTF-16 LE\n\
            make sure files_and_delays.txt is saved as UTF-16 LE\n\n"
        );
    }
#endif
    printf("\ntesting UNIX\n\n - - - - - - - - - -\n\n");
    printMap(mapAndMutexObject.fileMap);
    testFunctions(mapAndMutexObject, fhelper, true);
    printMap(mapAndMutexObject.fileMap);
    fullResetCount = 0;
    fhelper.resetFile();
#ifdef _WIN32
    fhelper.getCharacter(byteOrderMark);
#endif

    for (auto& it : mapAndMutexObject.fileMap)
    {
        it.second.position = 0;
        it.second.fullResetCheckNumber = 0;
    }

    printf("\n\ntesting Windows\n\n - - - - - - - - - -\n\n");
    printMap(mapAndMutexObject.fileMap);
    testFunctions(mapAndMutexObject, fhelper, false);
    printMap(mapAndMutexObject.fileMap);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        printf("\ntest start\n\n");
        MapAndMutex mapAndMutexObject;
        testInputs(mapAndMutexObject);
    }
    catch (char const* e)
    {
        printf("%s", e);
    }

    printf("\ntest finished, press Enter to exit\n");
    char ch = getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Be consistent

Some parts of your code use `std::printf()`, others just `printf()`. Be consistent, and [prefer using `std::printf()` in C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606023/when-using-c-headers-in-c-should-we-use-functions-from-std-or-the-global-na), especially if you `#include <cstdio>`, which you should remember to do.

## Parsing integers

In the constructor of `MapValue` you declare a `long long int delay`, but in the end it is going to be pushed into `delaysVector` as an `int`. It looks like you do this to catch mistakes where the value being read is larger than an `int` can hold, but of course this check itself will fail if the value is larger than a `long long int`. Consider using [`std::from_chars()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars). In particular, this can read into an `int` and will return a `std::errc:result_out_of_range` error code if the number in the input didn't fit into an `int`.

## Use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` for exit codes

It is a bit nicer to use [`EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status) instead of numeric exit codes.

## Make even more use of C++

You already improved on the original code, but there are still a lot of things where you use the plain old C way of doing things, but where you should use C++ features, as C++ provides much better (type) safety than C.

In particular, string manipulation is an area where C++ is much better, especially C++17. If you have a C string and want to find, say, the last `'/'` in it, you can use `std::string_view` to efficiently do that:

```
FILE* fopen(const char* path, const char* mode)
{
    svType path_view(path);
    auto last_slash = path_view.find_last_of('/');
    auto filename = (last_slash == path_view.npos) ? path_view : path_view.substr(last_slash + 1);
    ...
}
```

Of course, it's even easier to do path manipulations by using [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).

## Counting the number of files matching a pattern

In the constructor of `MapAndMutex` you are trying to find the file named `files_and_delaysNNN.txt` with the highest value of `NNN`, but you do this by trying to open each file in turn. This is quite inefficient. Instead, you can just ask for a directory listing. In C++17 you would use the cross-platform [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator), in C you would use [`opendir()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) and related functions on POSIX platforms, and on Windows of you have to use [`FindFirstFile()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) and related functions.

## Use structured bindings

In C++17 you can use [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to make code working with `std::pair`s and `std::tuple`s more readable. For example:

```
for (auto& [key, value] : fileMap)
{
    value.fullResetCheckNumber = 0;
}
```

## `FileHelper` is badly designed

The design of `FileHelper` is not robust against misuse. For example, consider calling `tryToOpenFile()` twice on the same `FileHelper` object, both times on files that do exist. The second call will overwrite `_f`, thus leaking a file descriptor. Why not make it so the file is always opened in the constructor, and no other functions can open a file? This will follow the [RAII principle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

The member function `checkIfFileExists()` should either be a free function or a `static` function, and the member variable `_fcheck` should instead just be a local variable inside `checkIfFileExists()` itself.

Apart from that, the only thing it does is some buffering and rewinding the file. Those are all functions that `<cstdio>` functions do themselves already. You could also use a `std::ifstream` instead. That brings me to:

## Parsing files

Just like you do a lot of manual string manipulation, you do the same with file input. You can rely a lot more on standard library functions, either from `<cstdio>` or `<fstream>`. Since the format of `files_and_delays.txt` is line-based, I suggest reading whole lines at ones using [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (or [`std::fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) in C), and then further parse each line.

## Code size

As you already mentioned in the previous version, some C++ functions will increase the size of the library significantly. This is holding you back from using some very convenient functionality, and instead spending a lot of time writing low-level code. Consider whether code size is important to begin with. Note that code size doesn't necessarily correlate with efficiency, and that where C++ will inline a lot of STL functions, C functions cannot do that but will instead be stored in the C standard libary, which will be loaded dynamically and thus still be in memory, even if they are not part of the .dll/.so file you are creating.

If code size is really the most important thing, then you should probably not use C++ at all, but just go for plain C.

## Don't `throw` raw strings

Avoid `throw`ing raw string literals. Prefer throwing exceptions that are derived from [`std::exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) or any of the derived types the standard library provides. For example, if you can't open a file:

```
throw std::runtime_error("fopen failure in tryToOpenFile");
```

Having a proper exception type makes it easier for code that catches exceptions to distinguish between exception types, without having to parse strings for example.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing again. I’d like the size to be small in places where speed won’t matter, like the part where the right file is found, but I think I should try to figure out how to avoid including the easyhook DLLs before focusing on that since they’re so big.